# Reduce the retry time in CoreData - see below

Tags: core-data, icloud

This is what appears in the log, see the Retrying after delay: 60 seconds

```
 2013-10-09 15:21:59.807 MyApp[4848:6507] -[PFUbiquitySafeSaveFile waitForFileToUpload:](299): CoreData: Ubiquity:  <PFUbiquityPeerReceipt: 0x15e09de0>(0)
        permanentLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x15e22100>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/HHWT75NS6T~com~xyz~MyApp/CoreData/New Project retry 2/mobile~A3BF465A-15C7-46F2-8C68-AC8F49FD15AB/New Project retry 2/W8MckEJ0x2d~HZZIeUH2be6hs41TEOONzKIrCuLcuP4=/receipt.0.cdt
        safeLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x15ec4660>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/HHWT75NS6T~com~xyz~MyApp/CoreData/New Project retry 2/mobile~A3BF465A-15C7-46F2-8C68-AC8F49FD15AB/New Project retry 2/W8MckEJ0x2d~HZZIeUH2be6hs41TEOONzKIrCuLcuP4=/mobile~A3BF465A-15C7-46F2-8C68-AC8F49FD15AB.0.cdt
        currentLocation: <PFUbiquityLocation: 0x15ec4660>: /var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/HHWT75NS6T~com~xyz~MyApp/CoreData/New Project retry 2/mobile~A3BF465A-15C7-46F2-8C68-AC8F49FD15AB/New Project retry 2/W8MckEJ0x2d~HZZIeUH2be6hs41TEOONzKIrCuLcuP4=/mobile~A3BF465A-15C7-46F2-8C68-AC8F49FD15AB.0.cdt

        kv: (null)

    Safe save failed for file, error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260 - Request for item properties on non-existent item.)" UserInfo=0x15eaedf0 {NSDescription=Request for item properties on non-existent item.}
    2013-10-09 15:21:59.809 iProjectiPad[4848:6507] -[PFUbiquitySetupAssistant finishSetupWithRetry:](811): CoreData: Ubiquity:  <PFUbiquitySetupAssistant: 0x15e4e520>: Retrying after delay: 60
```